# script for actionscript/flash and c++

Tags: c++, flash, scripting

I havent used flash or action script much. I am planning a small project that i'd like to be online via flash but i'd like to reuse the code in my c/c++ projects

Is there a script language i can use? i am thinking lua or python. After googling i found flua which is incomplete and jython. Can i use java in flash? would it be a good idea to use python in java which is ran with flash?

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)?

> With Alchemy, Web application developers can now reuse hundreds of millions of lines of existing open source C and C++ client or server-side code on the Flash Platform.  Alchemy brings the power of high performance C and C++ libraries to Web applications with minimal degradation on AVM2.  The C/C++ code is compiled to ActionScript 3.0 as a SWF or SWC that runs on Adobe Flash Player 10 or Adobe AIR 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Haxe? http://www.haxe.org

The Haxe compiler can produce swf files, JavaScripts and other, with a language that resembles ActionScript or JavaScript more or less, depending on what language details you care about.

Here's this nice teaser from the haxe site: "Currently in testing, with the right build of Haxe from Hugh Sanderson, you can now output your Haxe applications to pure C++ source code, complete with makefiles."

But no, I don't know about using Java inside a Flash. You mean the Flash app executing Java while it's running? or using Java to create a Flash app?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to embed Java within a Flash movie.  If you're creating a SWF that will display in a browser then you're restricted to Actionscript.  You could create a Java applet, load it in the same page, and use javascript to communicate between the two, though I wouldn't recommend that.

If you're using a projector to create an EXE then you may be able to load and use C++ dlls, though I've never attempted this.